# Efficiently counting pairs of integers in an array having difference greater or equal to k

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of integers, how can I efficiently calculate the number of pairs of integers with a difference of at least k? My goal is to do this in better than O(n^2) time.

Comment: Seems this question should be on the computer science site, https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Suppose that array is k, 2k, 3k, ..., nk. So that is O(n^2) pairs and you need output all them

Comment: @mrflash818 This doesn't look like a good fit for the cs site (which looks to have more advanced questions).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code! Sounds like homework.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to list them, you might need to list every pair which would be O(n^2). If you just need to count them, you can get O(n log n) by sorting the list, then for each start_index, find the smallest end_index for which the difference in values is at least k. There will be n - end_index of these.

Each successive step is to increment start_index by 1, then increment end_index until the difference in values is at least k, again add n - end_index, and repeat.

Here's O(n) code (in Ruby) for a sorted array.

```
def count_pairs (arr, k)
    count=0
    end_index = 0
    0.upto(arr.length - 1) do |start_index|
        while arr[end_index] - arr[start_index] < k do
            end_index += 1
            return count if end_index >= arr.length
        end
        count += arr.length - end_index
    end
    return count
end
```

If the list is already sorted, this is O(n).

Comment: but again the worst time complexity would be of O(n**2) e.g. array is [1,2 ,3,4,100] and k = 50

Comment: @Atulkumar No. Each index moves through the array once for O(n) time, and we do O(1) work at each step. If this list is sorted this is O(n), and it's doing the sort that makes this O(n log n)

Comment: @Atulkumar I posted sample code so you can see why this is O(n) for sorted arrays.

Comment: for the example i mentioned [1,2 ,3,4,100] and k = 50 array is sorted and lets say i start from element 1 and for 1 i have to go up to the last element that is 100 and this is same for all the elements so comparisons for element 1 is  4, 2 is 3 , 3 is 2 and for 4 is 1. Total comparisons are 10. now consider if there are n elements then total comparisons would be n + (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ..... + 1 that is O(n**2). Hope you got my point !

Comment: the solution for this question can only be solved in O(nlogn) that is first sort the array and for every element find the first element(Binary search)  in the right side of array that satisfy the condition and get the count. so overall complexity would be O(nlogn)

Comment: The code I posted is linear for a sorted array. The overall time is O(n log n) if you need to sort the array. If you're having a hard time seeing why my code is linear, stick a counter in the inner loop and run it for some sample inputs.